# Unable to switch to Iframe using WebDriver or Katalon Studio

Tags: selenium-webdriver, iframe, katalon-studio

We are automating the 2 different brands of e-commerce websites for same country. So most of the functionalities are same.

When i try to enter the payment details which there in Iframe, It is working fine for brand1 website. But in brand2 website, i am unable to switch into iframe.

when i use selenium code, it is displaying the error message "no such frame: element is not a frame".

when i use katalon studio code, it is displaying error message "Unable to verify image 'Object Repository/Japan/Payment/iframe' present"

[Code from WebSite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DT0x.png)

[Katalon Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lMii.png)

Can you please help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you show the Katalon script?

Comment: I have added the Katalon script in the description. Please find the "Katalon Script" link

Comment: Please show how is 'iframe' object defined. In object repository or wherever. And btw, it is better to copy and paste actual code than to show screenshots.

Comment: It is possible iframe definition is correct for one of the brands, but not for the other.